# How does gmail, gtalk, yahoo and other chat services keeps the login status as always available android?

Tags: android, authentication, status

How does all the chat applications in android keep the user permanently online?
I am developing a simple chat application with the help of smack client.
The thing is whenever the app starts it has to login to maintain its status with the server. 
I want to keep the status of the login permanent to the server just like gtalk, yahoo, facebook etc keeps.
Any suggestion/solutions guys?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK GTalk & Gmail app uses Shared preference to store the username & password of Google account. At the very first run application asks user to enter his/her credentials & store it in the shared preference. Thereafter when everytime user starts gmail or gtalk app, it fetches these details from shared preference & use it for authentication while syncing the accounts.

Hope it will help.

Comment: I know this part....I am talking about u log in to the application...then you force close the app without signing out.....a frnd sends me a message after 3 hrs.....and i recieve it.....How does that happen?

Comment: @Wishy If i have understood your problem correctly, you don't want to display login screen everytime. am i right? If yes then, at app startup you will check if username & password is available in the Shared preference. If available then you will directly navigate user to user home page or else you will display login screen.